# Does updating SNI config affect SSL Certificates and Validation

Tags: validation, ssl, sni

I'm developing an app for a non-tech client that has outsourced the backend to another developer. We'll be launching the app under 7 different branded app, over a series of weeks. Each app is exactly the same, sans for the domain the API end points are on (IIS hosted).

As part of our security, we validate the SSL certificate when we connect to the API, and ensure the key returned by the API server matches our hardcoded version of it, as to prevent man-in-the-middle attacks to sniff our REST calls. We have this functioning now for the current server (1 of 7 to be rolled out).

We've asked the backend guys to provide the certificates for the remaining 6 sites, so we can deploy the apps with the expected keys. However, they claim that as they will be rolling out the sites individually over the coming weeks, each time they bring a new a new site online, they said they are "updating the SSL certificate" which is required as they are "using SNI on the server, so each time a new site is added, the certificate will change, and the hardcoded validation for the existing sites will break".

Now whilst I'm no dummy, I'm also not a server admin, and only 99.9% sure that the SNI configuration to support another cert on the server, will not have any affect on the current certs already hosted for the existing domains. As a result, I wanted to explicitly confirm that the cert key we're validating as part of the SSL auth, is not going to change with each revision of the SNI config. The backend devs have essentially shut us down claiming we're paranoid, and going "beyond what is required" and to not expect "the same security a the major players offer" (as I mentioned that any decent commercial app validates its connection).

Is anyone able to confirm (or correct) my understanding of SNI as it relates to the certs, primarily that as they bring new sites online, that changes to the SNI have 0 impact on the existing certs for the current sites?

Edit: Whilst the use of multi-domain certs would regenerate the key, we can assume that they could generate/re-issue a multi-domain cert now in advance of the domains coming online. The question of if it's affected by the SNI config remains.

Answer (score 0):

> "updating the SSL certificate" which is required as they are "using SNI on the server, so each time a new site is added, the certificate will change, and the hardcoded validation for the existing sites will break".

This is a weird argument. The point of SNI is that they can have multiple sites (domains) on the same IP address where each has its own certificate. If they add a new site only a new certificate for the new domain need to be created and all the other certificates will continue to work: a client using SNI will tell which site it wants to visit and the server then can pick the appropriate certificate. If they instead could not rely on SNI then they would have to use certificates which cover all sites on the same IP address.

So while it can be that they have some process  which requires this kind of reissuing certificates it is not a requirement because of use of SNI, but only because they designed their process this way.